# Are the parquet files generated by IBM Db2 Event Store readable by a standard reader?

Tags: db2, parquet, ibm-event-store

I am looking at the documentation for IBM Db2 Event Store and I see the following statement "The data in the shared zone is stored in standard Parquet format and can be queried through Db2 Event Store or other systems that are capable of reading Parquet data." Where are the files located ? Can I read them using a standard parquet file reader ?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Db2 Event Store supports both a shared file system, like NFS, and Cloud Object Storage to store the shared files. In both cases the directory structure is similar, so I will describe the COS version of it.

Using the AWS S3 client you can query the files inside a COS bucket, in this case I am querying a test bucket in SoftLayer's COS and only showing the small number of parquet files that I have there. Like you can see in this listing, the files are all under a database directory named EVENTDB (the default database name), followed by the database identifier (DB00000000), followed by an internal identifier (TS00000003), then followed by data, finally a table identifier (t0000000000). Inside that directory there are two sub-directories: preShared and shared, and within them you find the parquet files. The shared files are the final set of parquet files, which are the result of the consolidation of preShared files. All files are immutable, but it is preferred to read the Shared stream, as preShared files are purged after being consolidated in the shared stream.

```
$ aws s3 --endpoint=https://s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud  ls --recursive s3://mytestbucket/ | grep -i parquet
2019-06-17 05:08:05       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000001.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 03:32:27       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000006.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 03:32:27       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000008.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 03:32:27       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000015.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 03:32:27       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000018.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 03:32:27       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000022.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:08:05       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000027.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:08:05       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000031.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 03:32:27       1004 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/preShared/s000035.0.0.i000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:49       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000001.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:50       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000006.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:51       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000008.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:50       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000015.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:50       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000018.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:49       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000022.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:50       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000027.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:49       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000031.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
2019-06-17 05:15:51       1057 ibm/htap/db/db2inst1/SHARED_DATA/EVENTDB/DB00000000/TS00000003/data/t0000000000/shared/s000035.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
```

Now all these files are just standard parquet files that can be read with a standard parquet reader, like Apache parquet-tools (https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools). Invoking parquet tools is quite simple, for example, the following allows you to see the metadata of one of the files above, after downloading it from COS using the standard AWS S3 client:

`$ java -jar /usr/local/parquet-tools/parquet-tools-1.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar meta s000035.0.0.t000000000000.parquet`

In the contents of the file you will see something like the following, which shows two internal columns (__beginTime and __prevRID), followed by the user created column c1:

```
file:        file:s000035.0.0.t000000000000.parquet
  creator:     Apache parquet-cpp
  extra:       LastShardLSN = 0:4764
  extra:       FirstBeginTime = 1541121073074

  file schema: T1
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  __beginTime: REQUIRED INT64 O:INT_64 R:0 D:0
  __prevRID:   OPTIONAL INT64 O:INT_64 R:0 D:1
  c1:          REQUIRED INT64 R:0 D:0

  row group 1: RC:1000 TS:8149 OFFSET:4
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  __beginTime:  INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:4062/8044/1.98 VC:1000 ENC:RLE,PLAIN
  __prevRID:    INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4066 SZ:32/30/0.94 VC:1000 ENC:RLE,PLAIN
  c1:           INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4098 SZ:4055/8044/1.98 VC:1000 ENC:RLE,PLAIN
```